# Call Back function doesn't work when call from child component

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-props

I want to change the parent state from the child component.
I think my code correct but doesn't work.

```
const [newValidate, setNewValidate] = useState<Array<boolean>>(new Array(checkList.length).fill(false));
```

this is my parent state

```
 {checkList.map((row, index) => {
        const changeValidate = () => {
          setNewValidate(newValidate.splice(index, 1, true));
        } return ( <>
                    <ConfirmButton callBack={changeValidate} />
                    <RejectButton callBack={changeValidate} />
                  </>)})}
```

and this is my map in parent component

```
export function ConfirmButton(props: ButtonProps) {
const { callBack } = props;
return (
<>
  <IconButton
    onClick={() => callBack()}
    className={classes.confirm}
    aria-label="confirm check"
  >
    <CheckIcon />
  </IconButton>
</>
);
}
```

and this is my child component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

[array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) mutates the array.

> The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing or
> replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements **in place**.

```
const changeValidate = () => {
  setNewValidate(newValidate.splice(index, 1, true)); // <-- mutation
}
```

## Solution

If you are trying to update the value at a specific index you need to shallow copy the entire state array. Map the previous state to the next state and when the mapping index `i` matches the enclosed `index` return the updated value, otherwise return the existing value. I suggest also using a functional state update since the next state array *depends* on the previous state array.

```
const changeValidate = () => {
  setNewValidate(
    newValidate => newValidate.map((el, i) => i === index ? true : el
  );
}
```